# Why isn't the facebook "like" button displaying on my page?

Tags: facebook

Could someone please take a few moments out of their schedule to look at the source code for the url: http://thered-line.com/petition-view.php?petition_ID=10 and tell me why the facebook "like" button is not appearing?

Thanks,

-Lance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your page. You could easily have spotted this using a debugger. 
(F12 in IE, FireBug Addon for FF, Ctrl+Shift+I in Chrome and Opera)

```
                <div id="fb-root">
                    <script>
                        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                            FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
                            xfbml: true});
                        };
                        (function() {
?> //syntax error
                            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
                            e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
                            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
                        }());
                    </script>
```